# Regularizing the $\log\log n$ series

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, riemann-zeta, divergent-series, zeta-functions

The divergent series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log n$$ can be regularized using the derivative of the Riemann zeta function at $s=0$:

$$-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\zeta(s)=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}n^{-s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}\log n$$

This yields $\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)$ as the answer. Is it possible to regularize the series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\log\log n$$ in a similar manner?

Comment: Is there a reason to believe you can?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't. I'm just curious about whether it can be regularized in some way and, if so, what its value would be.

Comment: It's just that if this is an exercise or homework problem, it would give a hint that there is a solution. But if it is idle speculation, it is quite possible that there is no such way to do it. As a rule, it is nice for the question reader to know if you have *reason* to believe there is such an answer, to give people who are going to donate their time to helping you an idea of the amount of time they are volunteering and whether they'd be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:
$$
f(s)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}e^{-s (\log n + \log\log n)}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n\log n)^{-s},
$$
so
$$
f'(s)=-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\log n + \log\log n)e^{-s(\log n + \log \log n)},
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\log \log n = -f'(0) + \zeta'(0) = -f'(0)-\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi).
$$
Certainly $f(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(s)> 1$, so the question is just whether it can be analytically continued to $s=0$.

Comment: Except that your deduction that it is $f'(0)-\zeta'(0)$ is not at all obvious. You have $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\log n )e^{-s(\log n + \log \log n)} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n ^{-s} (\log n)^{-s}\neq \zeta(s)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Certainly that's right.  I am using the presumed "fact" that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\log n = -\zeta'(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

i make the admission up front that I am not an analytic number theory expert but what about approaching this by noting that the sum of divisors function $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d|n}d$ was shown by Gronwall in $1913$ to be written as $$\limsup \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \log \log n} = e^{\gamma}$$
Where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

Comment: Certainly not going to get to a closed form for the above. How could it - the $\limsup $ doesn't tell us anything about an single value. And the sum above is obviously divergent in the tranditional sense, so $\limsup$ is not going to be useful in any event.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for the reply - I knew I wasn't adding any real tangible *value* with my comment. Happy to delete if you think similarly. Best, A.